# RaspberryPi call from Android

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle

I've made an app on my RaspberryPi that always when I type in my browser "rspi_ip/light" it switches on the LED. How using Spring I can execute it from the Android app? How this operation is called?

Comment: I think you want to call a HTTP URL of your service from the app.

Comment: @Simulant yes exactly as I mentioned at below comments comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create an **API** of the command sent from your rasp which can be created using Spring/boot. then use that API in a native app, developed using java to toggle the light. That's the industry approach. 
**HACK/SHORTCUT** - Many third-party apps automatically fetch the request from your rasp and you can send that command easily from that app. 
**HOPE THIS HELPS!** 
ping me if you need any other help or app link or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: https://github.com/Daniel-Avo/RaspberryPi-Locer-Controller/tree/development  This is my app on raspberry, I just want this mobile app to poke this address and trigger the light.